# New custom list item is not adding to Arraylist while retrieving image from firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, sharedpreferences, firebase-storage

I am trying to store firebase data as offline dataset. So in that case I have retrieved firestore data to a list which is passed to `addCrops()` methods as `List<CropsModel> data`. Using this List's data I am trying to retrieve the firestore storage image data which I have previously stored to firestore storage which is working totally fine. The problem is I am trying to combine the image data and the `CropsModel` List data to a single List `mData` which is a List of `CustomListItem_Cultivation` type. But for some reason data is not storing to the list. I have checked the `mData` list's size out of the loop is 0 whereas `CropsModel` List's size is 5. Thus there is no data is converting to `json` to store `sharedPreferance`.

```
 private void addCrops(final List<CropsModel> data) {
        Log.d("checked", "crops here");
        for (final CropsModel crop : data) {
            StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("gs://app-597o.appspot.com/crops/").child(crop.getNameEnglish() + ".jpg");


            try {
                final File file = File.createTempFile("image1", "jpg");
                storageReference.getFile(file).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, baos);
                        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
                        String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
                   mData.add(new CustomListItem_Cultivation(crop.getNameBangla(),crop.getNameEnglish(),imageEncoded));
//                        Log.d("datasetCrop", crop.nameBangla + " " + crop.nameEnglish + " " + crop.cropPicture + " " + crop.cropPicture.length);
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json= gson.toJson(mData);
        editor.putString(CULTIVATION_ITEMS,json);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

**CustomListItem_Cultivation.java**

```
package com.example.app.model;

public class CustomListItem_Cultivation {


     public String nameBangla;
     public String nameEnglish;
     public String userPhoto;

    public CustomListItem_Cultivation(String nameBangla, String nameEnglish, String userPhoto) {
        this.nameBangla = nameBangla;
        this.nameEnglish = nameEnglish;
        this.userPhoto = userPhoto;
    }


    public String getNameBangla() {
        return nameBangla;
    }

    public String getNameEnglish() {
        return nameEnglish;
    }

    public String getUserPhoto() {
        return userPhoto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out that the problem is occurring due to time delay of data loading from firebase storage. I have solved this by the code below.

```
 private void addCrops(final List<CropsModel> data) {
      
        for ( final CropsModel crop : data) {

            StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("gs://farmersapp-31e06.appspot.com/crops/").child(crop.getNameEnglish() + ".jpg");

            storageReference.getBytes(1024*1024).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {


                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, baos);

                    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

                    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);


                    mData.add(new CustomListItem_Cultivation(crop.getNameBangla(),crop.getNameEnglish(),imageEncoded));
                    if(data.size()==iterationCnt)
                    {

                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        String json= gson.toJson(mData);
                        editor.putString(CULTIVATION_ITEMS,json);
                        editor.apply();

                    }
                    iterationCnt++;

                }
            });

        }
       
    }
```